# Route to another page from a sub-page

Tags: elm

I am using [Hop](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/sporto/hop/6.0.1/Hop) at the moment and I am wondering how you can route to another page outside the `main` / `app` module. If you follow the Hop documentation, there are two specific types of messages, well - they are called that in the docs, `NavigateTo` and `SetQuery`. How do you raise those messages from sub-modules?

I have tried the following:

```
view =
    button [ onClick (Main.Types.NavigateTo "test") ] []
```

However, this would mess up the typing.

Comment: Could you share some more info/ code? If you are navigating outside Main /App, are you trying to navigate to somewhere outside your elm app? What do you mean by "messing up the types"?

Comment: @wintvelt Being confused about how update functions exactly work and what you can exactly do in Elm was a big breakpoint. I self-answered my question with an example of how I temporarily fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem wasn't with Hop, but my understanding of how parent-child communication works within Elm. To say lightly, you need to be careful for what and when you use this type of communication, but in my case, I read a few good blog posts by [Brian Thicks](https://www.brianthicks.com/post/2016/06/23/candy-and-allowances-parent-child-communication-in-elm/) and [Alex Lew](https://medium.com/@alex.lew/the-translator-pattern-a-model-for-child-to-parent-communication-in-elm-f4bfaa1d3f98#.c5wnjhu4k) talking about this form of communication. Especially Alex' post is typical for my use case.

What I did is the following: I added a separate update statement for the type of message I want to route. This is not the best implementation and it can be done more elegantly like Alex describes with the translator pattern.

```
update msg model =
    case msg of
        NavigateTo path ->
            let
                command =
                    Hop.outputFromPath hopConfig path
                        |> Navigation.newUrl
            in
                ( model, command )

        SetQuery query ->
            let
                command =
                    model.address
                        |> Hop.setQuery query
                        |> Hop.output hopConfig
                        |> Navigation.newUrl
            in
                ( model, command )

        ExampleMsg InterestingMsg exampleInteger ->
            update (NavigateTo "<path here>") model --Update model in let-statement

        ExampleMsg subMsg ->
            let
                ( updatedExampleModel, pageCmd ) =
                    Page.Example.State.update subMsg model.exampleModel
            in
                ( { model | exampleModel = updatedExampleModel }, Cmd.map ExampleMsg pageCmd )
```

Comment: Maybe useful to point out that the elm community is moving away from "components" structure (each with its own Model. update, view) like in Brian Hick's blog post). Instead, the common practice is to have a "flat" structure. It is explained well [here in the official guide](https://guide.elm-lang.org/reuse/). My favorite (bigger) example is the [time tracker SPA](https://github.com/knewter/time-tracker), which also includes routing (but not HOP)